# Resizing UITableViewCell on tapping a button in it

Tags: ios, uitableview

I want to put a button in a UITableViewCell which should work like this:
when I tap the button the cell should display full content of the cell otherwise display only part of its contents. The height of the UITableViewCell will be taller after the full content is revealed. Basically it should look like the style in iOS's app updates. How can I do this?

I've tried

```
[tableView beginUpdates];
[tableView endUpdates];
```

but this only change the size of the cell and put the content in the middle of the cell. I want the part that is originally visible on the cell unchanged and only display more content after the height of the cell becomes taller.

My init method for the custom UITableViewCell:

```
- (id)initWithStyle:(UITableViewCellStyle)style reuseIdentifier:(NSString *)reuseIdentifier
{
    self = [super initWithStyle:style reuseIdentifier:reuseIdentifier];
    if (self) {
        self.backgroundColor = [UIColor clearColor];

        self.opaque = NO;
        self.textLabel.autoresizingMask = UIViewAutoresizingFlexibleBottomMargin;
        self.detailTextLabel.autoresizingMask = UIViewAutoresizingFlexibleBottomMargin;
    }
    return self;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

If you want to change the height of a table view cell it requires not only altering the table view cell but the amount of space the table view allocates for it.  Return the desired size from tableView:heightForRowAtIndexPath: and reload that row (eg: via reloadRowsAtIndexPaths:withRowAnimation:).

Answer (score 0):

Try setting the autoResizingMask of the subviews in your UITableViewCell to achieve the desired effect.

`UIViewAutoresizingFlexibleBottomMargin` will keep a view pinned to the top.

`UIViewAutoresizingFlexibleTopMargin` will keep a view pinned to the bottom.

`UIViewAutoresizingNone` will keep it centered without stretching.

`UIViewAutoresizingFlexibleHeight` will make a view stretch taller/shorter as your cell changes its height.

For each subview, figure out how you want it to behave and set the values accordingly.

Comment: I put this to init method of my cell and there is no effect.